# How make regular expression that not repeated lookahead

Tags: c#, regex

My current code is:

```
const string st = "one two";
const string reg = "((?<first>one ))?(?=(?<second>two))";
var result = Regex.Matches(st, reg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLn(result.Count);

foreach (Match match in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("first={0}, second={1}", match.Groups["first"], match.Groups["second"]);
}
```

Output is:

```
2
first=one , second=two
first=, second=two
```

that return two matches.

How I can write the regular expression to return only one match?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you make your first group optional, btw. you can remove one set of brackets of the first group.

1. So, your regex matches the "one" and lookahead to the following "two" (and stores that also in a capturing group).
2. Then, because the first one is optional it matches the second time the empty string before the "two" and lookahead to the following "two" (and stores that also in a capturing group)

Why do you need the lookahead, when you capture it then?

You should describe what you try to achieve.

**Try to answer your question:**

To get only one match, **make the first group not optional:**

```
const string reg = "(?<first>one )(?=(?<second>two))";
```

**or remove the lookahead:**

```
const string reg = "(?<first>one )?(?<second>two)";
```

this would now mean, if there is "one two" it matches as your first match. It the first is missing ==> "two", then it would only match the second group.

**What if you add an anchor to the start?**

```
const string reg = "^(?<first>one )?(?=(?<second>two))";
```

`^` matches the start of the string, so it should not match a second time before the second word, when the first one is available.

Comment: You should provide more examples and what you expect. It is unclear for me what you want to achieve. Is the second group also optional, or is it always there, when there is a first group?

Comment: thanks stema, but first group is optional for me."two" is possible too

Comment: no, second group not optional.i want this lookahead run only for first time and continue and not backtracking to "two"

Comment: I added a second solution to my answer.

Comment: Makes no sense to me, but I added another solution